Ubuntu 22.04 randomly freezing on HP Elitebook
Good morning,
I have an HP Elitebook (almost 2 years old) and had Ubuntu running on it for the last 2 years (no partition or anything, details below). In the last 10 days, my laptop randomly freezes. I can sometimes get into the console (using Ctrl+Alt+Prt_Scr) and restart the X window server using lightdm, but sometimes even that does not work anymore. I ran a whole bunch of hardware checks yesterday (using the hardware checks in the HP Bios), all of them were fine. So I think it has something to do with the graphics driver, but I am really not an expert here .... (and I hope I gave you the right information in the right format). Any help would be very much appreciated!
Thank you very much
Mary

inxi -Fxz 
System:
  Kernel: 6.8.0-40-generic x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: N/A Desktop: GNOME 42.9
    Distro: Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)
Machine:
  Type: Laptop System: HP product: HP EliteBook 840 Aero G8 Notebook PC
    v: N/A serial: <superuser required>
  Mobo: HP model: 880D v: KBC Version 30.4D.00 serial: <superuser required>
    UEFI: HP v: T76 Ver. 01.13.01 date: 03/30/2023
Battery:
  ID-1: BAT0 charge: 38.3 Wh (84.7%) condition: 45.2/53.2 Wh (84.8%)
    volts: 12.5 min: 11.6 model: Hewlett-Packard Primary status: Charging
CPU:
  Info: quad core model: 11th Gen Intel Core i7-1165G7 bits: 64 type: MT MCP
    arch: Tiger Lake rev: 1 cache: L1: 320 KiB L2: 5 MiB L3: 12 MiB
  Speed (MHz): avg: 531 high: 940 min/max: 400/4700 cores: 1: 940 2: 400
    3: 908 4: 400 5: 400 6: 400 7: 400 8: 400 bogomips: 44851
  Flags: avx avx2 ht lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx
Graphics:
  Device-1: Intel TigerLake-LP GT2 [Iris Xe Graphics] vendor: Hewlett-Packard
    driver: i915 v: kernel bus-ID: 00:02.0
  Device-2: Luxvisions Innotech HP HD Camera type: USB driver: uvcvideo
    bus-ID: 3-2:2
  Display: wayland server: X.Org v: 1.22.1.1 with: Xwayland v: 22.1.1
    compositor: gnome-shell driver: gpu: i915 resolution: 1920x1080~60Hz
  OpenGL: renderer: Mesa Intel Xe Graphics (TGL GT2)
    v: 4.6 Mesa 23.2.1-1ubuntu3.1~22.04.2 direct render: Yes
Audio:
  Device-1: Intel Tiger Lake-LP Smart Sound Audio vendor: Hewlett-Packard
    driver: sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl bus-ID: 00:1f.3
  Sound Server-1: ALSA v: k6.8.0-40-generic running: yes
  Sound Server-2: PulseAudio v: 15.99.1 running: no
  Sound Server-3: PipeWire v: 0.3.48 running: yes
Network:
  Device-1: Intel Wi-Fi 6 AX201 driver: iwlwifi v: kernel bus-ID: 00:14.3
  IF: wlp0s20f3 state: up mac: <filter>
Bluetooth:
  Device-1: Intel AX201 Bluetooth type: USB driver: btusb v: 0.8
    bus-ID: 3-10:3
  Report: hciconfig ID: hci0 rfk-id: 0 state: up address: <filter>
    bt-v: 3.0 lmp-v: 5.2
RAID:
  Hardware-1: Intel Volume Management Device NVMe RAID Controller driver: vmd
    v: 0.6 bus-ID: 00:0e.0
Drives:
  Local Storage: total: 476.94 GiB used: 149.4 GiB (31.3%)
  ID-1: /dev/nvme0n1 vendor: Samsung model: MZVLQ512HBLU-00BH1
    size: 476.94 GiB temp: 27.9 C
Partition:
  ID-1: / size: 467.89 GiB used: 149.32 GiB (31.9%) fs: ext4
    dev: /dev/nvme0n1p2
  ID-2: /boot/efi size: 511 MiB used: 81.9 MiB (16.0%) fs: vfat
    dev: /dev/nvme0n1p1
Swap:
  ID-1: swap-1 type: file size: 2 GiB used: 0 KiB (0.0%) file: /swapfile
Sensors:
  System Temperatures: cpu: 39.0 C mobo: 25.0 C
  Fan Speeds (RPM): N/A
Info:
  Processes: 317 Uptime: 20m Memory: 15.36 GiB used: 3.8 GiB (24.7%)
  Init: systemd runlevel: 5 Compilers: gcc: 11.4.0 Packages: 2737 Shell: Bash
  v: 5.1.16 inxi: 3.3.13



If you have no partition where is Ubuntu installed?

I'm in the same boat, and been there forever. The freeze only happens while on battery, never on power supply. I'm running 24.04, tried to run XOrg and Wayland, nothing helps. I never tried with another linux dist though - maybe that's an idea.
